# sitecore.context.database.getitem returns null during publish pipeline

Tags: publishing

Created a custom processor to execute translation during publish process:

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.CheckSecurity, Sitecore.Kernel" 
<processor type="Feature.Translation.Commands.TranslateOnPublish,Banner.Feature.Translation" 
<processor type="Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.DetermineAction, Sitecore.Kernel"
```

while working on the class which is inheriting PublishItemProcessor is returning the value of
Sitecore.Context.Database null.

Answer (score 3):

You should not use `Sitecore.Context.Database` in any backend job. It may be `null` there, or sometimes `core`, or sometimes `master` if you start some job manually.

You should use your `item.Database` property instead, e.g.:

```
public class CustomPublishProcessor : PublishItemProcessor
{
    public override void Process(PublishItemContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            Item sourceItem = context.PublishHelper.GetSourceItem(context.ItemId);
            var database = sourceItem.Database;
```

Comment: I am trying to use context.PublishHelper.GetTargetItemInLanguage(item.ID, Sitecore.Globalization.Language.Parse(DestLanguage)); but this is coming null always   @Marek Musielak